# How to subset a dataset using d3.js according to change in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have a data set [Can be viewed here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/82cd19eff7db367193cf8ce00144a40ea8d140ac/data.json) and a dropdown menu with country names (key attribute in the dataset). Now if I select one country from the drop down menu how can I subset the dataset upon the change to present only values of the selected country. The code that I have right now only outputs [object Object]

[**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9w1wa9j/7/)

code:

```
function checkIt(data) {

    var countriesByName = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) {
        return d.Country_Names;
    })
        .entries(data);
// creating dropdown    
    var data = JSON.stringify(countriesByName)
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown_container")
                   .append("select")
                   .attr("class", "selection")
                    .attr("name", "country-list");

    var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("option");
         options.text(function (d) { return d.key; })
       .attr("value", function (d) { return d.key; });

// detecting change in drop down
var changePie = function() {
    //get the data value and index from the event
    var selectedValue = d3.event.target.value;
    var selectedIndex = d3.event.target.selectedIndex;

    //alert("You selected the option at index " + selectedIndex + ", with value attribute "+ selectedValue);

    var selectedDOMElement =
        d3.event.target.children[selectedIndex];
    var selection = d3.select(selectedDOMElement);

// subsetting data    
var uniqueData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(selection) { return selection.key; })
    .entries(data)
    .map(function(entry) { return entry.values[0]; });

//Output selected country with all its values
    console.log ("your selection is" + uniqueData)

    //making Pie 
function makePie() {
return ("you have made a Pie for" + " " + selection.text())
};
    alert(makePie());
};   

d3.select("#dropdown_container").on("change", changePie);           
};



d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/82cd19eff7db367193cf8ce00144a40ea8d140ac/data.json", checkIt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9w1wa9j/16/)

Your `uniqueData` is an object that contains the whole data. What you want is to get the values for the selected index(selected country). To see the values in the console, expand the message.

It doesn't seem that you need `d3.nest` at all (if all you want is to get the values for a specific key)

Comment: Thank you all I needed was one line  var uniqueData = data[selectedIndex].values[0];